# How do I use a Tidal Scheduler variable in sqlcmd?

Tags: sql-server, tidal-scheduler

We're using Tidal 6.5.3.164.  I'm running a SQL Server stored procedure using sqlcmd.  It works when I specify the server but I want to use a Tidal variable for the server and it's not working.  In the Command line I have sqlcmd.  In the Command Parameters I have:

`-E -S <Group.Report_Server> -Q "exec dbo.test_sproc"`

I get the following error messages:

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. .
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
```

My guess is sqlcmd is trying to connect to a server named <Group.Report_Server> because it works fine when I specify the actual server name.  Any idea's how to use the variable with sqlcmd?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the Tidal variable was defined several levels higher and not in scope when I ran this.  Normally this would run fine but the way I was trying to run it didn't work.  Everything works as expected, I just had to learn more about Tidal.